# How to create a script that connects points in an animation?

Tags: modeling, animation, python

I want to create a script driven animation with Blender. I want to create an animation of lines connecting a bunch of vertices.

Is it possible to do this?

How would I change the properties of the line and vertices (color, thickness, textures, etc.).

Comment: Just wondering what shape you have in mind? (Organic, Mechanical, Architectural)

Comment: Are you after a rendered animation or do you need the geometry?

Comment: The questions isnt very clear, what part needs to be animated? the connecting of the lines? The final output needs to animate? animate in what way?.

`lines connecting a bunch of vertices.` isnt really very descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

w = 1 # weight
cList = [Vector((0,0,0)),Vector((1,0,0)),Vector((2,0,0)),Vector((2,3,0)),Vector((0,2,1))]

curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name='Curve', type='CURVE')
curvedata.dimensions = '3D'

# Line thickness:
curvedata.bevel_depth = 0.05
curvedata.fill_mode = "FULL"

# Point size
point_size = 0.1

# Line colour:
line_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Red")
line_mat.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)
curvedata.materials.append(line_mat)

# Point colour
point_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Green")
point_mat.diffuse_color = (0, 1, 0)

objectdata = bpy.data.objects.new("ObjCurve", curvedata)
objectdata.location = (0,0,0) #object origin
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(objectdata)

polyline = curvedata.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(cList)-1)
for num in range(len(cList)):
    x, y, z = cList[num]
    polyline.points[num].co = (x, y, z, w)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(x, y, z), size=0.1)
    bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(point_mat)
```

Base on this [blog post](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.fr/2011/05/blender-25-python-bezier-from-list-of.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do that. Read the way Blender stores mesh information [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html). Either two vertices are connected with an edge, or they're not. One possible way to do that is to use vertex-duplicated object to represent each vertices:

[image: Vertex duplication]

... and animate thin meshes connecting them (maybe using bones connected to one end of each "edge" objects, or auto-generated shape keys). Then your concerns turn to a simpler matter of tweaking material.